# excluir nome de pessoas dum array em C

Tags: c

Olá. Tenho um algoritmo em C para excluir um usuário, mas não interagir no array:

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<stdlib.h>  
#include<locale.h>  
#include<conio.h>  

#define numeroUSER 100  

char nome[numeroUSER][100] = {"João Carlos","Maria Luisa","Pedro José", "Gerente"};  

int main() {  
excluirUsuario();  
}  

void excluirUsuario() {  
int indice=0;  
printf("informe o indice: \n");  
scanf("%d", &indice);  

for (int i=0; i<numeroUSER; i++) {  
nome[i]100] = nome[i+1][100];  
}  
}
```

Se eu digitar o índice 0, quero que exclua joão da lista, já que é o primeiro e permaneça o restante. O algoritmo não exclui e eu acabo apagando parte dos nomes, ou seja, consigo me posicionar na string, mas não consigo me posicionar entre os índices com os nomes. Como faço essa exclusão. Obs, é um tratalho de lógica de programação.

Comment: Olá André tu tens que digitar o nome e em cima desse nome encontrar e deletar do array? Irá ter 100 nomes cada array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu código alguns erros e confusões.

- `nome[i]100] = nome[i+1][100];` - aqui faltou um `[` para que a sintaxe estivesse certa, mas suspeito que isso se terá perdido ao construir a pergunta aqui ?

  De qualquer forma, cada string é dada apenas pelo primeiro indice, assim `nome[i]`, pois os `100` já tem a ver com as letras de cada uma. Ao fazer `nome[i][100]` estaria apenas a copiar a letra na posição `100` não mexendo nas restantes.

  E também não poderia fazer `nome[i] = nome[i+1]` pois se trata de um array de `chars`, logo tem de utilizar [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/), que é a função indicada para copiar `strings`. Assim:

  ```
  strcpy(nome[i], nome[i+1]);
  ```

  Que copia a string em `nome[i+1]` para `nome[i]`.
- `for (int i=0; i<numeroUSER; i++) {` - Se quer copiar os nomes para as posições anteriores um a um, tem de começar naquele que quer excluir e não no `0`.

  Se está a utilizar o elemento da frente no `for` também não pode ir até ao ultimo pois não existe nenhum à frente, logo o fim deveria ser `numeroUser - 1`.

Corrigindo esses pontos o seu `for` ficaria assim:

```
for (int i=indice; i < numeroUSER - 1; i++) {
    strcpy(nome[i], nome[i+1]); //copia o de i+1 para i
}
```

Agora é importante lembrar que quando for mostrar os nomes que sobraram, tem de mostrar menos `1`, que corresponde ao tamanho atualizado após a exclusão:

```
printf("Usuarios restantes: \n");
int tamanho = numeroUSER - 1; //tamanho atualizado devido ao usuario removido
for (int i=0; i< tamanho; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", nome[i]);
}
```

[Veja este exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/2xvy2b)

Recomendações:

- Você incluiu o *header* `locale.h` mas acabou por não utilizar a função `setlocale` para definir a codificação a ser utilizada.
- Evite utilizar `conio.h`, pois ela é especifica para windows. No código apresentado nem existe qualquer função que dependa deste *header*.
- Indente o seu código. Isso é bem mais importante do que possa pensar, e o código que tem na pergunta não tem qualquer indentação.
- Não defina funções para baixo das suas chamadas. Repare que a função `excluirUsuario` vem depois do `main`, quando ela é utilizada no `main`. Deve de fazer a declaração da função antes do `main`, ou move-la completamente para antes do `main`.

Answer (score 0):

1º Crie uma variável char auxiliar;

2º Você deve pegar o índice que entra de parâmetro na função e percorrer o array da `,` até a `,`  correspondente; (Se existe inúmeras "," poderá ser mais fácil criar um vetor de int para armazenar as posições que ocorrem as ",")

3º No momento que achar o nome pode por dentro da auxiliar;

4º Faça um laço de repetição (semelhante a um bubble sort) e passe a ultima posição da `,` até a primeira;

Ou podes utilizar a função strtok (ou strtoke) para separar...

***Exemplo:***

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```